# Debugging angular 2 performance

Tags: angular

I've notice that my angular 2 app is becoming a bit sluggish.  For example, the time between clicking on a button (which sets some state) and having the result displayed (based on that state value) has some (~1 sec) delay.  I suspect that there are some performance issues in some of the methods that are called during each change detection loop.

Can anyone provide guidance on:

1) How to time how long each change detection loop takes?

2) How to pinpoint those method calls that are significantly contributing to the delay?

Thanks.

Comment: You can probably identify the bottlenecks just by looking at your code. Any http calls? Manual `detectChanges()`? Long running calculations? Huge arrays displayed with `*ngFor` instead of pagination? Otherwise there shouldn't really be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Within Developer tools in chrome, under "Profiles" panel, you can run the profiling type `Record JavaScript CPU  Profile`, which will record the execution time of functions, and that should help you detect which functions contribute the most to the delay of your app.

**UPDATE**

This feature is now found in the "Performance" panel [since Chrome 58](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/devtools-javascript-cpu-profile-migration-2/). Open the "Performance" panel and [click the "Record" icon](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/#record) to start profiling the page.
[image: record button on Performance tab]

There are other types of profile types within that tab that should help you too. Here's a link to help [analyze the Chrome profile](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/#analyze) generated when you stop recording. A similar functionality also exists in Internet Explorer.